# Indices of elements in an array in order from smallest to largest

Tags: code-golf, array

**Task**

Basically you have an array of random integers e.g.

```
I() = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1]
```

and you have to create another array of the same length with the numbers 1 to the size of the array in place of the smallest to largest numbers respectively, e.g.

```
O() = [1, 7, 5, 3, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

For duplicates, the first occurrence is taken as the smaller of the indices.

**Test Cases:**

```
Input:   I() = [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4]
Output:  O() = [1, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4, 2, 6]

Input:   I() = [1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 6, 5]
Output:  O() = [1, 7, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 6, 10, 11, 9]
```

**Rules**

1. It should work with array of any finite length
2. All integers are positive(greater than 0)
3. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: I feel like this must be a duplicate.

Comment: @GregMartin I am not sure I am new to golf code so if you can find the link to the same question on golf code I'd be happy to remove this question from here.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85835/8478) (The opposite operation in a way.) (Edit: Actually, it's the same thing...)

Comment: Can we assume some upper bound on the input values and list length like 255 or so?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes I think 255 is okay

Comment: This is similar to [Imitate an ordering](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62587/imitate-an-ordering/62664#62664) where the source is always `[1..n]` and you have to handle repeats.

Comment: Also similar to [Rank a list of scores with “skips”](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35528/rank-a-list-of-scores-with-skips) which handles ties differently and ranks highest to lowest.

Comment: Regardless of all the discussion whether this is a duplicate: nice first challenge and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Unfortunately, after overcoming my general confusion with ordering-based problems, it turns out that this is an exact duplicate of the first challenge I linked.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
f l|z<-zip l[0..]=[sum[1|q<-z,p>=q]|p<-z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkFNTZaNblVmgkBNtoKcXaxtdXJobbVhTCBTUKbCzLYytKQAyY//nJmbmKdgqFBRl5pUoqCikKUQb6iiY6igY6ygYITFMdBTMwMg09j8A)

Haskell doesn't have build-in sorting, so we have to roll up our sleeves. We pair each element with its index with `z<-zip l[0..]`, then for each pair counts the number of pairs that are smaller or equal. This first compares the values, then tiebreaks by their index.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, 28

```bash
f()(nl|sort -k2)
f|f|cut -f1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@moamRl1NTnF9UoqCbbaTJlVaTVpNcCuSkGf7/b8hlwmXMZcRlCiYNAQ).

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 2 bytes

[`⍋⍋`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u234B%u234B1%204%203%202%205%203%202%201&run)

`⍋` is the symbol for [grade up](http://help.dyalog.com/15.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Grade%20Up%20Monadic.htm) - return a permutation that sorts the argument. Applied twice, it does what's asked for in this problem. Indices in Dyalog are 1-based by default.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 96 bytes

```
f=(a,b=a.length,c=[...Array(b)])=>(m=a.lastIndexOf(Math.max(...a)),a[m]=0,c[m]=b--,m?f(a,b,c):c)
```

```js
f=(a,b=a.length,c=[...Array(b)])=>(m=a.lastIndexOf(Math.max(...a)),a[m]=0,c[m]=b--,m?f(a,b,c):c)

console.log(f([1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.zip(1..999).sort.map{|x,y|y}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2uXWJ2oV5VZoGGop2dpaampV5xfVKKXm1hQXVOhU1lTWVv7v0AhLTraUMdUx1jHBEwa6ZjExv4HAA)