# Mario Kart Scoring w/ Ties

Tags: code-golf, array

I ran into this problem while working on another challenge I'm making for this site. In that challenge I utilize "[Mario Kart 8 Scoring](http://mariokart.wikia.com/wiki/Driver%27s_Points)". The amount of points the player in *k*th place gets is represented by this 1-indexed array: [15,12,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]. So 1st place gets 15 points, 2nd place gets 12 points, etc.

It's easy enough to assign points like this, however the tricky part comes with how I handle ties. What I do is give each tying player the average of the points given for each tying place. For example, if only 1st and 2nd tied, then both players get (15+12)/2 = 13.5 points. (Note: You're allowed to round to the nearest int, so 13 or 14 are both also acceptable.) Then 3rd - 12th place get the normal amount of points for their position.

### Challenge

Given 12 non-negative integer scores that are decreasingly sorted, output the number of points each player gets. You can also take the points list [15,12,10,9,...] as input. Note that the number of points each player gets does not depend on the actual values of the scores, but how they compare to the other scores.

### Test Cases

- [21,21,15,14,12,9,6,5,4,3,2,1] => [**14,14**,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
- [20,15,15,15,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3] => [15,**10,10,10**,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

  - explanation: (12+10+9)/3 = 10.3333
- [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] => [**7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7**]

  - explanation: (15+12+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1)/12 = 6.8333
- [20,20,20,20,10,10,10,9,8,7,6,5] => [**12,12,12,12**,***7,7,7***,5,4,3,2,1]

  - explanation: (15+12+10+9)/4 = 11.5, (8+7+6)/3 = 7
- [100,99,98,95,95,95,94,93,93,92,91,91] => [15,12,10,**8,8,8**,6,**5,5**,3,**2,2**]

  - explanation: (9+8+7)/3 = 8, (5+4)/2 = 4.5, (2+1)/2 = 1.5

Related: [Rank a list of scores with "skips"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35528/rank-a-list-of-scores-with-skips)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(p)(s)`, where ***p*** is the list of points and ***s*** is the list of scores.

```js
p=>s=>s.map(v=>s.reduce((t,x,i)=>x-v?t:t+p[n++,i],n=0)/n)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

p=>s=>s.map(v=>s.reduce((t,x,i)=>x-v?t:t+p[n++,i],n=0)/n)

points = [15,12,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(points)([21,21,15,14,12,9,6,5,4,3,2,1])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(points)([20,15,15,15,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(points)([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(points)([20,20,20,20,10,10,10,9,8,7,6,5])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(points)([100,99,98,95,95,95,94,93,93,92,91,91])))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 3 bytes

Apparently R has a built-in for this. Takes a list of `p`oints and `s`cores as input.

```r
ave
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nck7CoAwEADR3pMkMEU2H80WHiaIfTDg9dcoCK@auazvh5OCRCSgVDZWCpnETH4Z7w9zKVrR8sto@kRUJm/tPl1neLMH)

Example:

```r
p=c(15,12,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

> ave(p,c(20,15,15,15,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3))
 [1] 15.00000 10.33333 10.33333 10.33333  8.00000  7.00000  6.00000  5.00000  4.00000  3.00000  2.00000  1.00000
> ave(p,c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
 [1] 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333 6.833333
```

Comment: Right tool for the job!

Comment: This should be 3 bytes (just `ave`) otherwise it's just a snippet (which isn't allowed). Fortunately, this saves you 5 bytes.

Comment: @caird thanks, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 109 +1 (-a) = 110 bytes

```perl
@p=(1..10,12,15);while(@F){$/=$,=0;do{$,++;$/+=pop@p}while($w=shift@F)==$F[0];push@r,(int.5+$//$,)x$,}say"@r"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrdCoIwGADQVxnyXUw29yOsH8ZgV971BNGFkOFA3IczLMRXbwVRcC4PdtNgcvboqBZCK65rrk1plz4MHfVNuYJ0wJ2y17gCZ8yCZA4jety@BxaX@nCbP9c5aM7qYvGeej9xGsZZGAZSAi8fwLfUPgs/FTnXivzpnyM5kD3ZEfOKOIc4plydjFBa5ap9Aw)

Includes 17 bytes to hardcode the point values.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*2 bytes off thanks to [@geokavel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46313/geokavel)!*

```
7#uti2XQw)
```

Inputs are a column vector (`;` as separator) of integer scores and a column vector with the points. The output contains the results separated by newlines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/31y5tCTTKCKwXPP//2gjQ2sgMjS1NjSxNjSytrQ2sza1NrE2tjayNozligZJAFkGQAkLa3MUSQA)
Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N9cubQk0ygisFzzv6JLyP9oI0NrIDI0tTY0sTY0sra0NrM2tTaxNrY2sjaM5YoGSQBZBkAJC2tzNEkjA7BGCEJTQkgv0E5skAgr4cgQhuAKCVpqABS3tLa0sLY0hSETa0tjMAJ63hCI8JsBAA).

#### Explanation

```
       % Implicitly take first input. 
       % STACK: [21;21;15;14;12;9;6;5;4;3;2;1]
7#u    % Unique consecutive integer labels
       % STACK: [1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11]
t      % Duplicate
       % STACK: [1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11], [1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11]
i      % Take second input
       % STACK: [1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11], [1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11], [15;12;10;9;8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1]
2XQ    % Average second argument as grouped by the first
       % STACK: [1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11], [13.5;10;9;8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1]
w      % Swap
       % STACK: [[13.5;10;9;8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1], [1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11]
)      % Reference indexing
       % STACK: [13.5;10;9;8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1]
       % Implicitly display
```

Comment: Nics solution! I think you can save some bytes by not rounding to nearest int (it's not required).

Comment: @geokavel Oh, you are right! I misread the challenge as requering rounding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
γ€g£vygFyÅAˆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZHTWvSDy0uq0x3qzzc6ni67f//aEMDAx1LSx1LCx1LUxgy0bE0BiMjHUtDIIrlijY01TE00jEEqtWx0DHXMdMx1THRMdYBCsUCAA)

**Explanation**

```
γ              # group the scores into chunks of consecutive equal elements
 €g            # get the length of each chunk
   £           # split the points list into chunks of these sizes
    v          # for each chunk y in the points list
     ygF       # len(y) times do:
        yÅA    # get the arithmetic mean of y
           ˆ   # add to global list
               # implicitly output global list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ṁ⁴Œg¤Æmṁ$€F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsZHjVuOTko/tORwWy6Qp/KoaY3b////ow1NdQyNdAwNdCx1LHTMdcx0THVMdIx1gEKx/6PNdbDCWAA)

-3 bytes thanks to fireflame for noticing new Jelly features :D

Comment: Yeah, it's probably too long looking at how short the solutions on the related challenge are.

Comment: @geokavel the annoying thing is that the code to generate the list is longer than the J solution on that one ;_;

Comment: I forgot to put that you can take the points list as input too. I'm going to add that.

Comment: [11 bytes.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsZHjVuOTko/tORwWy6Qp/KoaY3b////ow1NdQyNdAwNdCx1LHTMdcx0THVMdIx1gEKx/6PNdbDCWAA "Jelly – Try It Online") Uses the new arithmetic mean monad instead of `S÷L` and mold instead of `xL`, which allows `$` instead of two `µ`.

Comment: I was planning on implementing a *key* quick in Jelly. If I had gotten around to it, based on the J solution, something like ``xÆm$ƙ`` might have existed.

Comment: @fireflame241 o cool, thanks!

Comment: Introducing the *key* quick `ƙ`. Now solvable (but noncompeting since the feature was introduced after the challenge) in [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW@7DnY0qx2Y@3NX3////aCNDHSAyNNUxNNExNNKx1DHTMdUx0THWMdIxjP0fDZIAsgyAEhY65iiSAA): `Æmṁ$ƙẎ`

Comment: @miles [Non-competing is not really a thing anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges).

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsajk9JrD7flAlkqj5rWuP3//z/a0FTH0EjH0EDHUsdCx1zHTMdUx0THWAcoFPs/2lwHK4wFAA)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 15 bytes

```
[:;<@(##+/%#)/.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzNCsIwEITveYqFILQ4bLNpI261Ij6AL@DBQ2mpXgr2/YmJPyAI32WG@eYe49jxpd3tj4W162ply4qNWfr5MSzUMUmAeBzaG1/FmfMpNySexJESc4rGDP00U@EFibxvsqLYIKBBDQ8paaT352cszkEVuoWGLw20fpFkSfxL3v6UMT4B)

Takes the list of scores (`1 2 ... 12 15`) as a right-hand argument and the   values to score as a left-hand argument. If this isn't a logical input, add 1 byte for a `~`-passive to invert the order in which the inputs are taken.

There might be a few things to golf, which include

- My usage of boxing
- The cap at the end

## Explanation

I'll split this into a couple functions.

```
avg_and_dupe =. # # +/ % #
score        =. [: ; <@avg_and_dupe/.
```

- `avg_and_dupe` takes the average of a list and duplicates it as many times as the list's length
- `score` scores an input (left argument) given a list of scores (right argument).

## avg_and_dupe

```
# # +/ % #
#           Length
  #         Copy as many times as the left argument
    +/ % #  Average
    +/       Sum
       %     Divided by
         #   Length
```

This works so nicely because it's treated as two [forks](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/fork). If you're still scratching your head (I know I was at first), ask and I can provide a more in-depth explanation for why this works as it does.

#### score

```
[: ; <@avg_and_dupe/.
                   /.  Key: using the values given, partition the scores
     <@avg_and_dupe     For each partition:
       avg_and_dupe      Average and duplicate
     <                   Then box
   ;                   Raze the boxes into a single list
```

If it's still confusing, I can also add an explanation for `/.`-key, but I think the [wiki page](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/slashdot#dyadic) explains it pretty well.

Comment: Note that OP added `You can also take the points list [15,12,10,9,...] as input.` if that saves you any bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 154 bytes

```cs
x=>s=>{for(int i=0;i<12;){int b=0,j=i,a=0,c=0;for(;j<12&&x[i]==x[j];j++,b++){a+=s[j];}a=(int)Math.Round(a/(b+.0));for(;c<b;c++){x[i+c]=a;}i+=b;}return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU89b4MwEJ3DrzhliGxxpZCPNsgxS6UOVbM0QwfEYBw3NUpMhElKhfjt1FBFan3PZ9979judtHeyrFRvxEnZs5AKdt@2VqfWk0dhLZxbz9ai1hKeL0ZutKnTDP/ex5wkYHjf8MTypP0oK@JY0DxkehPNGW2HMuchFlyjcKd00vCMFU6fzZpUZ5w3aZGxwvcx933aCp/bgegEH9zoVtSfwVt5MXsi7knuByGlvx5ykzM5fHE2vsy4YJ32ec66StWXykDDup7dpriWeg9boQ2xdaXNIc1AVAdLvdabXEUFFjgY9QXjWNBCtEKI5m6HCDHCGuER4QHB0UuEBcKgQce8yVNpbHlUwXula/WqjSK7sUPwUrpuU5wiMeSfdRhiHGO8xnh1wxLjxYg5xpEDdJRY6hbzuiH6Hw)

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform) + using Linq, 170 + 23 bytes

```cs
x=>s=>x.GroupBy(z=>z).Select(y=>Enumerable.Repeat(Math.Round(s.Skip(Array.IndexOf(x,y.Key)).Take(y.Count()).Average()),y.Count())).Aggregate((a,b)=>a.Concat(b)).ToArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLasMwEDzXX7HkJMNW5NnGpDakpS19hEJc6CHkoNgb1ySRXUlO7Zh8u6sYQgkawe6sNMNspK@jTFEjxY50LiKCsNKGdvw9lT@1E22F1pDXjjbCpBE8FTK6S6VZLPGijrNitaXFMghg7TelH2g/KPmzyor8vmIHPzi4PKQtRYZVfvAoix0pYX/wOeUkDJsJ883nWSFjpnm4SXM2VUpU/EXGVH6sWYkVf6PKdfmn2BCr@IN9a5jtp3urlJAt8Z@1dJIoSoQhxgSuXD8Qdigja7U6iWStPHObyTnZPktjmIlUMm1UKpPFEoRKtFs7V3uhQIMPkn6hzQs19EYIvb69XQQPYYxwi3CDYOkhwgDhNIPjxLmytjqzSb9UashulVjYGvDXzJp1sINszS6ku130PPTG6I3OGKI3aNFHr2cBR5dpm9OdOMfTaf4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun.*

```python
lambda s,p:[sum(p[s.index(i):][:s.count(i)])/s.count(i)for i in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/djoMgFITveYpzqcmkK1S7xcQnYbnonylJi6Ro0n169yxW26SF7@aQYc5M@O3PnVdj2/yMl911f9xRRKhNHK5ZMHHl/PF0z1xeW1PH1aEbfM@Tzb@eQ9vdyJHzFO3Yn2IfqSEjiI9REoysIEtIBY0NKpRYQ0FaPDRFEkwUrNnie9bNGvb4dF8sFuTMYrSYFPyoobfQ1UwJvU5wOMlYYYUInfNTi/9I6i1VSi/E0juVrtOScOOv1GYONLnk4x8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda s,p:[sum(v for j,v in zip(s,p)if j==i)/s.count(i)for i in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NDoIwEITvPMXeaJNRaQG1JPgEvgFy8CfEEgQCaqIvj1sUL5p@h2ZnZjPbPq7npg6HIt0N1f5yOO2pR5tk/e0i7lQ0HZW4k63paVvBirQFlWlq5aKfH5tbfRVWOpd1nj4ftqnItAKjYqgISsNgiRgRQmioHF6mg1F8E7C@xmryOJ2z/94n@kVNfBeM4YAHBmYNE09EMOEIl1FMLj3Pla5c6W3iUdtZvsTf1T6oAvFntvEhJ6EQPMxcW/1TeDxKyuEF)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>108</s> 70 bytes

```python
lambda s,p:[1.*sum(v for j,v in zip(s,p)if j==i)/s.count(i)for i in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9LDoIwGIT3nOLf0ZoRaQWlJHgCb4AsfIRYg4UAmujlsUVxo@m3aObRTJtHf66NHMpsN1T76@G0pw5Nmotg1t2u7E5l3dIFd9KGnrph1uS6pEuWab7ogmN9Mz3T3KW0y3TFsM1YLgUsIoaIICQUVogRYQkJUcDLZTiab0LrJ1hPGefb7r/zqX4RE98HxnJoBQWVQMUTEdRyxI4RloJ7nhtdudHb1KOm1aYnf2d8UAV3mW98THrJrJa7sfJn7/gnPrwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 152 bytes

```
f::[Int]->[Int]
f=concat.g(15:12:[10,9..1])[]
g[q]t _=[q:t]
g(q:r)t(x:z)|x>head z=(replicate(l(q:t))(sum(q:t)`div`l(q:t))):g r[]z|1<2=g 
r(q:t)z
l=length
```

It's a pain to import `groupBy` and `on`, so I had to do my own.

Averaging function will be shortened shortly.

Needing the signature could probably be avoided with compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
lambda s,p:[sum(p[s.index(i):12-s[::-1].index(i)])/s.count(i)for i in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BbsIwEETv@QrfEksTmnWSFluCL@APjA9QGmEpOBEGqXx92IQmlyK/gz3jWc32j9u5C@XQbPZDe7gcTwcR0Rsb75est3Hlw@nnN/PSkMqjNSYnt2hOfsTVd3cPN3403VV44YOIbthtMqsIDNWgCqSg8YkaFUookENiVTGZLwr21/ia/4w@Z9@dv@gCzSwDpnDBgoZeQ9czFXQ5wWWIcTJJxtLtWHpnEtFfPW@S7kMK0ULwJd@mkLPRZCzasa36V3haSsrhCQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 62 bytes

```
(s,p)=>[sum(p[s.index(i)to][to s.count(i)])/s.count(i)for i:s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcgxCgIxEEbhq6TMwM9q1FVXWC8yTKUGUpgJmSx4@5jORl71vlK1ae5x7d5QaL2zbW9f2KaUn6@PT9RUuKmz6aFbbgOEdr@JWl26mfRS04DoOeBvAsdhRjgg7LHgigvOmHHCEYOEqH8B)

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 63 bytes

```
(s,p)=>map(i=>sum(p[s.index(i)to][to s.count(i)])/s.count(i),s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYixDsIwDAV/paMtPRVSKNAh/ZEoAwIqZWhs1anE34dsXdAtd6ebFMl18ZUMyn5en0rJz7avpMH6lN@fLyUuEkORzvqX7Lm0Efl0BIyrbqn5QsHhLxFdcCPcAHfGhAfuuGHEFRe0FZnrDw)

Comment: ^^ I'm just gonna start with Proton next time lol.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 14 bytes

```
∊{(⊂≢⍴+/÷≢)⍵}⌸
```

Takes the list of scores as left argument and points list as right argument. Add 2 bytes for wrapping it in `()` if called directly and not as a named function.

`{`...`}⌸` group right argument by key in left argument and apply function in braces to each group (key operator).

`⊂≢⍴+/÷≢` is a fork where:

`+/÷≢` is average points for group (sum divided by tally)

`≢⍴` tally reshape (replicate the average to match number of items in group)

`⊂` boxes the result (this is to counteract the mixing of the result that the key operator applies)

`∊` is enlist and flattens the result of the key operator (which is a nested vector of vectors) into a simple list.

[TryAPL online](http://tryapl.org/?a=20%2020%2020%2020%2010%2010%2010%209%208%207%206%205%28%u220A%7B%28%u2282%u2262%u2374+/%F7%u2262%29%u2375%7D%u2338%2915%2012%2010%209%208%207%206%205%204%203%202%201&run)